# XML import InDesign fails

Tags: xml, import, adobe-indesign

When I try to import an XML file into InDesign CC, I have to select the XML file multiple times while it's importing the file.

Sometimes I have to select it six or seven times before it finally finishes importing.

I have validated the XML file and it showed no errors.

Does anybody have an idea on how to resolve this?
If you need extra info, please ask!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As Loic stated in his answer, it is no normal. Are you running the import manually or through the script? Are any links to external files in the source xml?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously not how it should work. Are you sure you are not required to select missing files stated in the XML file ? Try update if not in latest version. Eventually rebuild preferences and in last resort, restart computer and InDesign.
If still no improvement, contact support that might be a bug.
Once again, never seen this behaviour in my whole career.

Answer (score 0):

Also, avoid importing an XML file from a server path with a pipe (|) character (or any other non-alphanumeric character) as a folder name, or file name. This may not be the cause in your case, but I had slightly different issues importing files and the badly named folder was along the path, not at the destination.